# How to write .htaccess to forward all requests to index.php in whatever subfolder they were made

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like every request to be forwarded to index.php but honoring which subfolder the request is made in. I can get them all to go to the root index.php, but not the index.php in the particular subfolder.

Example: 
site.com/testurl **>** site.com/index.php
site.com/admin/testurl **>** site.com/admin/index.php
site.com/randomname/randomname **>** site.com/randomname/index.php

I dont want to hard code any subfolders so that it stays dynamic.

Currently, I have this as my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Push every request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Extra credit (Not sure if this is even possible with .htaccess): 
Making it so that it knows if an index.php is in the subdirectory and if not then falls back to the root index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Determines whether the request doesn't end with index.php:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$

# Redirect to the requested path, followed by index.php:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$    /$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. 

If I put your code in and replace my last rewrite rule with yours then it works for subdomains, but not the main domain anymore.

And both rules together dont seem to work as expected.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the root: You need to add `RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ /index.php [L]`

Comment: Adding it gives a 500 server error. Replacing it still only works on subfolders.

Comment: @DavidEdwards I've updated my answer and tested that it works in these cases: `site.com/foo` => `site.com/index.php`, `site.com/foo/bar` => `site.com/foo/index.php` and `site.com/foo/bar/baz` => `site.com/foo/bar/index.php`.

Comment: One little issue... its ignoring files that are actually there...  So site.com/foo/bar.php does not work

Comment: See my updated answer which ignores existing files.